# Can't find the HTML file #!portfolio-item-2.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, r-portfolioanalytics

I have been working on this free template and it's very great, but on reaching the portfolio page, I encountered a snag. The HTML code is below:

```html
<div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-groups='["photography", "web", "video"]'>
  <a href="#!portfolio-item-2.html" class="hover-overlay">
    <img alt="Project 2" src="images/portfolio/preview/2.jpg" />
    <div class="overlay background-90-a">
      <div class="hidden-xs">
        <p class="title heading-a">YouTube Video</p>
        <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Excepteur sint lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</strong></p>
        <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square heading-a"></i></p>
      </div>
```

The part that talks about a `<a ref...>` refers to a HTML file (portfolio-item-2.html) that I cannot seem to find in the template documents.

What should I do?

Comment: Where I have have issue is for the file being linked to and not the html code

Answer (score 0):

You are using #! in href.
Try this:

```html
<div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-groups='["photography", "web", "video"]'>
          <a href="portfolio-item-2.html" class="hover-overlay">
           <img alt="Project 2" src="images/portfolio/preview/2.jpg" />
           <div class="overlay background-90-a">
            <div class="hidden-xs">
             <p class="title heading-a">YouTube Video</p>
             <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Excepteur sint lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</strong></p>
             <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square heading-a"></i></p>
            </div>
 Run code snippetCopy snippet to answerHide results
```